# Help wth number to roman numeral Python script

Tags: python, arcmap

I am trying to convert numbers (up to 30) to roman numerals. Using a script for another field calculator function as a template, I created this script that doesn't want to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def NumberToRomanNumeral ( !CONCESSION! ):
 if CONCESSION == "1":
  newstr = "I"
elif CONCESSION == 2:
 newstr = "II"
elif CONCESSION == 3:
 newstr = "III"    
elif CONCESSION == 4:
 newstr = "IV"    
elif CONCESSION == 5:
  newstr = "V"  
elif CONCESSION == 6:
 newstr = "VI"  
elif CONCESSION == 7:
 newstr = "VII" 
elif CONCESSION == 8:
 newstr = "VIII"  
elif CONCESSION == 9:
 newstr = "IX"  
elif CONCESSION == 10:
 newstr = "X" 
elif CONCESSION == 11:
 newstr = "XI"
elif CONCESSION == 12:
 newstr = "XII"
elif CONCESSION == 13:
 newstr = "XIII"
elif CONCESSION == 14:
 newstr = "XIV"
elif CONCESSION == 15:
 newstr = "XV"
elif CONCESSION == 16:
 newstr = "XVI"
elif CONCESSION == 17:
 newstr = "XVII"
elif CONCESSION == 18:
 newstr = "XVIII"
elif CONCESSION == 19:
 newstr = "XIX"
elif CONCESSION == 20:
 newstr = "XX"
elif CONCESSION == 21:
 newstr = "XXI"
elif CONCESSION == 22:
 newstr = "XXII"
elif CONCESSION == 23:
 newstr = "XXIII"
elif CONCESSION == 24:
 newstr = "XXIV"
elif CONCESSION == 25:
 newstr = "XXV"
elif CONCESSION == 26:
 newstr = "XXVI"
elif CONCESSION == 27:
 newstr = "XXVII"
elif CONCESSION == 28:
 newstr = "XXVIII"
elif CONCESSION == 29:
 newstr = "XXIX"
elif CONCESSION == 30:
 newstr = "XXX"


else:
   newstr = ""
return newstr
```

Comment: Is there a particular error message that you're getting?

Comment: There are some existing scripts out there to do the conversion. For example, take a look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81611-roman-numerals/

Comment: Is your input numeric or string? Your first if statement uses quotes while the rest don't.

Comment: I'd say check your tabs as well as the data types as kenbuja notes. you could coerce into the appropriate type via something like elif int(CONCESSION) == 28: - I'd also second the use of an existing script for that.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer your question directly, but one thing you might consider in the future for doing this kind of conversion are Dictionaries, which are a built-in Python datatype that are a much easier alternative to long elif lists. See: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html. Saves some typing, and probably easier to find issues in the code. But my guess is your problem what kenbuja brought up - if your input is a string, you need to make sure all of your statements are checking for string values.

Comment: I think you need...
Expression: NumberToRomanNumeral(!CONCESSION!)
then
Code Block starting...
def NumberToRomanNumeral(CONCESSION):
then decide if CONCESSION is number or text (needs quotes) for the if statements
then instead of lines like
newstr = "I"
use
return "I"

Comment: Got it to work! The error was on the first line. Instead of ( CONCESSION ) it was input as ( !CONCESSION! ). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why has no one criticised the horror of this code snippet using the fact that it should be more procedural?

Answer (score 1):

Exclamation marks are in wrong place - it should be

Expression:

```
NumberToRomanNumeral(!CONCESSION!)
```

Code Block: starting...

```
def NumberToRomanNumeral(CONCESSION):
```